# Using specs2 matchers within secondary functions

Tags: scala, specs2

I have a set of specs that have *a ton* of repeated code. I keep calling the same method with different inputs, and making the same set of assertions about the result.

I'd like to use a function to reduce the repetition, sort of like the example below.   Is there any way to do that?  If so, is there a way to do it so that my assertions can just be mixed throughout the function body and so that the function return type doesn't have to be a matcher?

```
"MyApp" should {
     "do something" in {
         tryOperation("large-one")
         tryOperation("small-one")
         tryOperation("another-one")
         //...
     }
}

def tryOperation(input: String): Result = {
    val result = classUnderTest.operation(input)
    result.foo must beEqualTo(bar)
    result.length must beGreaterThan(0)
    result
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like `org.specs2.execute.Result.foreach`

```
"do something" in {
  Result.foreach((1 to 10).toList) { i =>
    i ==== i
  }
}
```